# How to handle file input in java when the file is provided using < operator and the output is written to a file using > operator?

Tags: java, input, output

I want to upload a program on Codechef and the way they test our code is :
java test < in.txt > out.txt

How to get that file in code ... Initially I assumed it to be in arg[0] command-line argument but that is not working. Also please explain how to output the result using >.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<` and `>` operators redirect standard input and standard output respectively, so given

```
java test < in.txt > out.txt
```

you will receive the contents of `in.txt` via `System.in`, and anything you write to `System.out` will go into `out.txt`.